# SSIS (VS2008) with Oracle OLE DB Source

Tags: oracle, ssis

I have a strange problem where in the DEV environment everything is fine but in PROD SSIS reports an error about conversion from unicode to non-unicode. This error happens at the OLE DB Source task level. So, I don't even get the chance to use Derived Columns to perform the conversion.

We installed BIDS on the production server and the task is flagged as in error. When I try to open the properties, it tells me that the metadata is different from what is in the DTSX file. When I accept the offer to automatically correct, all faulty columns input type (External and output columns) have their type switch from `DT_WSTR` to `DT_STR`.

The descriptions of the tables involved are identical in DEV and PROD (same types for the columns). If I query for the character sets they are identical in both environment.

For your information, here is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM v$nls_parameters 
where parameter 
       like '%CHARACTERSET'
```

which returns:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET                   WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET             AL16UTF16
```

on both environment.

Any idea to solve this ?

Thank you,
Michel

Comment: Smells strongly like you have different version of drivers installed/configured. Ran into a similar issue with MySQL Drivers a long while back. Version X.Y.Z.13 was developed against. Server got driver version X.Y.Z.14 and boom, invalid metadata.

Comment: Sorry if I took time to answer, but you were right, it was the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running into a difference in the drivers installed/configured on the different machines.

I ran into a similar issue with MySQL Drivers a long while back. Version X.Y.Z.13 was developed against. Server got driver version X.Y.Z.14 and boom, invalid metadata.

You will want to examine the Dev and prod server version of metadata and determine which one is right for you. In my case, the Dev driver produced varchar (non-unicode) strings and that aligned with the target system whereas the newer driver they had installed in prod deduced they should have been nvarchar (unicode) strings. Reworking the nvarchar to varchar or changing the tables was outside of the allowable timeframe for the project and the insane rules the data management team used for table creation.